# Pyparsing behaviour

Tags: pyparsing

Does anyone know why this pyparsing code matches "/*function BBBBB()*/ runs on Component" after function AAAAA in this example? Used pyparsing version is 1.5.7. This example works correctly in case when 'body' variable is not defined with SkipTo(LineEnd()) but in this situation there is no comment matched right after last "}"

```
import sys, re, os
from pyparsing import *    
text = '''

module Setup
{
import from MODULE all;

function AAAAA() runs on Component
{
        // body
} // THE END OF AAAAA
/*function BBBBB()*/ runs on Component
{
        // body
/*
  function DUMMY() runs on Component return Type3
  { // body } }}}
*/
} // THE END OF BBBBB
function CCCCC() runs on Component return Type3
{
        // body
} // THE END OF CCCCC
}
'''

header = Keyword("function")
name = Word(alphanums + '_')
params = nestedExpr("(",")")
extras = ZeroOrMore(Word(alphanums + '._'))
body = nestedExpr("{","}") + SkipTo(LineEnd())

grammar = originalTextFor(header + name + params + extras + body)
grammar = grammar.ignore(cppStyleComment)

for result, start, end in grammar.scanString(text):
    print "{0}\nFound at position [{1}:{2}]".format("-" * 40, start, end)
    print result[0]
```

This is the output

```
----------------------------------------
Found at position [40:153]
function AAAAA() runs on Component
{
        // body
} // THE END OF AAAAA
/*function BBBBB()*/ runs on Component
----------------------------------------
Found at position [268:355]
function CCCCC() runs on Component return Type3
{
        // body
} // THE END OF CCCCC
```

Answer (score 1):

`SkipTo(LineEnd())` is going to start looking for the next newline from wherever the current parse position is. In your grammar, when you include `SkipTo(LineEnd())`, then before looking for that, pyparsing will look for whitespace or ignorable expressions to be skipped over, which advances the parse position. In your case, there are 2 ignorables, the two comments. After moving past the second comment, pyparsing then performs the `SkipTo(LineEnd())`, which pulls in the text 'runs on Component'. Finally, because you are using `originalTextFor`, the entire original string from the opening '{' to the last 'runs on Component' gets returned as the body.

Try changing `SkipTo(LineEnd())` to `SkipTo(LineEnd()).leaveWhitespace()`, and see if you get better results.

Comment: Unfortunately your solution doesn't work. It is easy to do the workaround remove SkipTo(LineEnd()) and find in the result last '\n' to extract it. Example: eol = text.find('\n', end); print result[0] + text[end:eol] but I do not like it